# How do I use regex on Netezza to find integers?

Tags: sql, regex, netezza, nzsql

I'm using the following function to find integers: `where  NZ_SQLEXTN..REGEXP_LIKE(d.ID, '[0-9]')`

I just noticed that it's not picking up negative numbers. When I do `where  NZ_SQLEXTN..REGEXP_LIKE(d.ID, '[^0-9]')`, the result set is all negative numbers.

How do I include negative numbers in the regex expression?

Comment: can you just not use arithmetic to find them? why a regexp?

Comment: `-?[0-9]+` is that what you are looking for? it's a bit unclear to me.https://regex101.com/r/nU6eJ6/1

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is actually matching only numbers from 0-9 it won't match negative nor floating points.

If you want to support more negative you can use:

```
-?[0-9]+
```

If you want to support negative and floating points, then you could use:

```
-?[0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*
or
-?\d+\.?\d*
```