# extract serial from string SQL Netezza

Tags: sql, string, netezza

please I need a query that could extract the Serial # from the Logmsg, the hard thing is that it does not follow a specific pattern, there is not fixed delimiter and the serial length is not the same always

```
|LogMsg                                                                                    |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Customer Receive CPE Indoor. serial 21530369847SKA011094, user:ahmed.o.haraz              |
|Customer Receive CPE Indoor as change. serial :21530369847SK9078291, user:Abdullah.M160275|
|Customer Receive CPE Indoor as change. serial :T5D7S18802909825, user:ahmed.o.haraz       |
|Customer Receive CPE Indoor as change. serial :T5D7S18802909830, user:ahmed.o.haraz       |
|Customer Receive CPE Indoor. serial ZTERRTHJ9303771, user:Mohamed.E176246                 |
|Customer Returned CPE. serial :21530369847SKA011094, user:ahmed.o.haraz                   |
```

the result will be like below:

```
|Serial              |
|--------------------|
|21530369847SKA011094|
|21530369847SK9078291|
|T5D7S18802909825    |
|T5D7S18802909830    |
|ZTERRTHJ9303771     |
|21530369847SKA011094|
```

Comment: You need a RegEx, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/37622585/2527905 Netezza supports regexp_extract(), e.g. `regexp_extract(logmsg, '\d[^,]*')`

Comment: it seems that extract the int from the string as if the serial starts with letters, it will extract only the int like this serial: ZTERRTHJ9303771  will be 9303771

Comment: Yep, sorry. Is the `:` optional in `serial :`?

Comment: yes, it not located in each serial. the query provided by Gordon is works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is `regexp_replace()`, but you have different formats for what follows `serial`.  So:

```
select replace(replace(regexp_extract(logmsg, 'serial [^,]+'), 'serial ', ''), ':', '')
```

Comment: please Gordon the provided query didn't work with this sample of Serial:  

Customer Receive CPE Indoor. serial:ZTERRT1H9202990

Comment: @AhmedMohammedAbdelKader . . . Perhaps you should ask a new question with more examples.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64254966/14311638

Use a combination of `regexp_extract_all_sp` and `get_value_varchar` along with the right regex pattern